# How to prevent payload of array got replaced by string of html on react redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, redux

So, I experienced weird things about my website. I already deployed my website to Heroku. All the GET request suddenly doesnt work, but all the POST request works just fine. But, when I run my website locally on development mode, it works for all the request type.

I guess its caused by my redux payload. Because, when I run my website on development mode, (look at the console of my redux dev tools), the payload of the contents array filled with an array of object, but when I run my website on production mode, the contents array got replaced to some sort of HTML string. How do I fix this?

Oh, by the way, the contents array is the one that the website has to map, and because it got replaced by a string, the website couldn't map it, so it shows the error.

These are the screenshots and source codes so you guys can better understand:

**Screenshots:**

1. Development Mode [image: Development Mode]
2. Production Mode [image: Production Mode]
3. The error [image: The error]

**Source Codes:**

1. [contentReducer.js](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/reducers/contentReducers.js)
2. [contentAction.js](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/actions/contentActions.js)
3. [Timeline.js](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/Components/Timeline.js)

and this is my website in which I am getting error: [InfoTech](https://infotechappsite.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: The action dispatched is `CONTENT_LIST_FAIL` and that sets [state.contentList](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/store.js#L23) to [this](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/reducers/contentReducers.js#L26) so [state.contentList.contents](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/Components/Timeline.js#L23-L24) is undefined. I guess you need to check why [this xhr](https://github.com/Team-E-HCI/Team-E-HCI.github.io/blob/source/frontend/src/actions/contentActions.js#L40) fails

Comment: @HMR What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Update the question with what went wrong with the xhr (dev tools network tab).